# Finding optimal Inflation - Walsh

Tags: macroeconomics

I am solving questions from Walsh and then verifying with a solutions manual. However, I keep solving a question and arriving at a slightly different answer than that suggested by the solution manual.

The solution given by the manual:

[image]

However, when I take the optimal $\pi^e$ and substitute into (121) I get

$$\pi^* = \frac{\pi^T[-1-\lambda]}{[-1-\lambda]} + \frac{\lambda k [ -1-\lambda]}{[-1-\lambda]} + \frac{\theta k [1+ \lambda]}{[-1-\lambda]} +e\frac{\lambda - \theta}{[-1-\lambda]}$$

and this simplifies to:

$$\pi^*= \pi^T + k(\lambda - \theta) - e\frac{\lambda + \theta}{[1 + \lambda]}$$

And so my issue is that I don't see how there is no $\lambda$ in the numerator of the fraction multiplying e at the end of the simplification.

Can anyone see my error? I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Found almost like you with a $\lambda - \theta$ for the last numerator. No sign of the $1+\theta$ . The solution seems weird as the factor on the "e" is $\lambda - \theta$ in equation (121) and I don't see how it can turn in what is here given as a solution ...

Comment: Which problem in Walsh is it? Maybe there's an errata somewhere for it. I got the same derivation as you.

Comment: #14, chapter 7. It is page 328 of 3rd edition. I think it is #11 of chapter 8 for the second edition.

Comment: 123, please share the knowledge (solution manual) ;)

Comment: Sure. Is there a way I can send you the file?

Comment: @123 just send the link to anoldmaninthesea@gmail.com . Thanks ;)

Comment: The mystery is over folks. The original people who made the question that Walsh got it from emailed me back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Roel Beetsma replied! He says he got the same derivation we basically got. So the solutions seem to be mistaken and we win! Also I'm removing the strikeout below.

[image]

Note that
$$+ e\frac{\lambda - \theta}{[-1-\lambda]}$$

actually simplifies to

$$ - e\frac{\lambda - \theta}{[1 + \lambda]} $$

rather than with $\lambda + \theta$ in the numerator like you had.

So the solutions has

$$- e \frac{1 + \theta}{1 + \lambda}$$

instead of what we have above. The difference between the two is:

$$-e\frac{-1 - \lambda}{1 + \lambda} = e$$

Comment: Mods, feel free to delete this if you feel it is a non-answer. I did email the original people who did the derivation (Beetsma and Jensen) that Walsh got from their paper, and linked them back here though.

Comment: Scorreeeeeeeeee

Comment: Do I get points for finding the error? Lol

Comment: I can only give you the 5 with my upvote lol.

Comment: Sorry 123 but your math were wrong so points go to Kitsune ! (However I had risen the minus sign before so technically I should attribute points to me lol)

Comment: Hah. Fair enough.